# How to create and save data in file after submit Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

if user selects a value and presses submit create
create a file having the name same as value in the repo you created.

I tried below code:

```
Storage::disk('public')->put($name, $file);
```

Comment: did you mean store a file with a file name which user enter?

Comment: Please read the documentation carefully. You would find the answer there.
It's a repeated question on stack overflow.

Comment: @NalinNishant: to create file with name of dropdown value selected

Comment: so you want to create a file with the name of dropdown input. and what type of file? is it uploaded by a user? give us a full explantation what you are doing

Comment: @NalinNishant  Just to create a new file after submit button clicked, nothing else

Comment: and the file is txt , img, pdf?

Answer (score 0):

For a text file, $filewould be the text, while for an image, it'd be the raw information that makes up the image.
Here is an simple example to achieve this

```
// Example 1: Save as the default type (JPEG)
Storage::put('public/images/my_profile.jpeg', $file->encode());

// Example 2: Save as a PNG
Storage::put('public/images/my_profile.png', $file->encode('png'));
```

to save a txt file

```
Storage::put( $name.'.txt','contents is written inside user_input_name.txt' );
```

Comment: let me know if it doesn't help u